# Finding the approximate probability of random variables that are normally distributed

Tags: probability

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ be independent random variables each having the standard normal distribution. Find (approximately) $P(80<\sum X_j^2<120)$, $j=1$ to $100$

Comment: Do you know how $\sum X_j^2$ is distributed?

Comment: Not sure on that. What I know is on the X's

Comment: Have a look at the Chi-squared distribution. Does that help?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#Definition).

Comment: Think that helps. Will I manipulate it in any way or use it as it is?

Answer (score 1):

The sum of squares of $k$ standard normal distributed random variables follows a Chi-squared distribution with $k$ degrees of freedom, i.e.
$$\sum_{j=1}^{100} X_j^2 \sim \chi_{k=100}^2.$$
Hence,
$$P\left(80 < \sum_{j=1}^{100} X_j^2 < 120 \right) = F_{\chi^2}(120) - F_{\chi^2}(80) = 0.8453$$
where $F_{\chi^2}$ is the cdf of the Chi-squared distribution with $100$ degrees of freedom. Values for $F_{\chi^2}$ can be obtained from tables or Matlab for example.